# WebSharper.UI.Next missing

Tags: f#, websharper, websharper.ui.next

```
open WebSharper.UI.Next.Client
open WebSharper.UI.Next.Html
open WebSharper.UI.Next
```

Don't know why after update the Nuget package WebSharper.UI.Next from 4.6 to 4.7, these namespaces are not available... But in the project file (.fsproj), the reference looks good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSharper.UI.Next was moved to WebSharper.UI some time ago.

Comment: So divAttr is no longer available?

Comment: And if I target to net48 instead of net5.0, it seems like they are still there?

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://developers.websharper.com/docs/v4.x/fs/ui to get a div you'd write ``div [ attr.id "bla" ] [ text "hello" ]``.